# How can I get the list of paused/cached acitvities which I see when the home-button is long-pressed?

Tags: java, android

When I long-press the home button on my phone, I can see a list of activities that I've recently launched. When I start another activity, Android caches/pauses the old activity.

I'd like to get the list of recently launched activities but I can't seem to figure out how. I dug through StackOverflow and the Android SDK documentation of [`ActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) and came up with these two snippets:

```
ActivityManager mgrActivity = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );

System.out.println("getRunningTasks: " + mgrActivity.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE).size());
System.out.println("getRecentTasks: " + mgrActivity.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED).size());
```

Neither of these show me the correct number of activities that I've recently launched. Both these calls return larger values than number of activities shown when I long-press the home button. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

---

I tried this to get the name of the activites:

```
ActivityManager mgrActivity = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );

for (RunningTaskInfo run :  mgrActivity.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    System.out.println(run.topActivity.getPackageName());
}

for (RecentTaskInfo run :  mgrActivity.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE)) {
    if (run.origActivity != null) {
        System.out.println(run.origActivity.getPackageName());
    } else {
        System.out.println(run.id);
    }                   
}
```

Comment: to begin with, `ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED` will return activities that have the exclude_from_recent flag, which are not displayed in the recent apps panel (obviously)

Comment: @njzk2, any suggestions on what I should change it to? The options are `ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED` and `ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE`.

Comment: I think that it's the flag, see the "Constants" section of the link you provided. You use the flag `RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED` - return all tasks, even those that have set their `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` flag, I think the correct one in this case is `RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE` -> Provides a list that does not contain any recent tasks that currently are not available to the user.

Comment: I've changed the constant and the tried the code again. I long-presses the home-button and swiped away all the running activities to close them. Now when I long-press the home-button, I get a screen that reads "No recent apps", but the modified code shows that there is one recent task. I'm a little confused as to what this is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the correct number of recent activities. It's funny how I haven't found this solution elsewhere.

```
ActivityManager mgrActivity = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );

for (RecentTaskInfo run :  mgrActivity.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE)) {
    if (run.baseIntent.getCategories().contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)) {
        System.out.println(run.baseIntent.toString());
    }
}
```